# How to make the if return the expected result (R)?

Tags: r, if-statement

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (A <0) {:
   the condition has length> 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (A> 0) {:
   the condition has length> 1 and only the first element will be used
```

```
A <- c (0, -2, -4,1,5)
B <- if (A <0) {A/-2} else if (A> 0) {A/2} else {A = 0}
```

Erro:
The result of B must be (0,1,2,0,5,2.5).

Comment: Please read the help page: ?’if’. And then read ?’ifelse’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is use `ifelse` instead of `if`. `ifelse` is used for vectors whereas `if`/`else` is for scalars.

```
A <- c (0, -2, -4,1,5)
ifelse(A < 0, A/-2, ifelse(A> 0,  A/2, 0))
#[1] 0.0 1.0 2.0 0.5 2.5
```

However, you don't need `ifelse` here as well since this can be simplified to just :

```
abs(A/2)
#[1] 0.0 1.0 2.0 0.5 2.5
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like to understand why the other way does not work. Could you explain?

Comment: I think I did. `if` is used for scalars meaning objects of length 1 since `length(A)` is greater than 1 it does not work here with `if` and hence you have to use `ifelse` for such vectors.